# Can I compile Capacitor apps for iOS on 2019 Intel MacBook Pro

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, capacitor

I have the opportunity to buy my used Intel MacBook Pro 2019 from work for a very good price. I would like to use it to compile my Capacitor apps for iPhone/iOS but I heard and read different things about whether this possible or not.

Some fellow developers told me that XCode won't install on Intel Macs anymore, but I was able to install it from the App Store.

I haven't had the chance to test the setup with Capacitor and XCode thoroughly yet (as it is not my machine yet), but one issue I imagine could be that I might not be able to compile for the latest iPad models (which have a M chip themselves) and possibly upcoming iPhone models.

Is this a legitimate fear? Are there other reasons why a Intel MacBook Pro 2019 may not be a feasible option to compile Capacitor apps for iOS? And what would be the alternatives to get such a setup that doesn't cost me thousands of €?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest version of macOS and Xcode on the Intel MacBook Pro 2019, so the '*XCode won't install on Intel Macs anymore*' part is incorrect.